# Showing that $X$ given that $X + Y = z$ is $U(0,z)$

Tags: probability

Let $X\in Exp(\frac{1}{a})$ and $Y\in Exp(\frac{1}{a})$.

I have to show that $X\mid X+Y = z\in U(0,1)$

I know this is just conditional probability,so all I have to do is to find joint pdf's and marginal pdf for $f_X$, and the divide the both to get the result. But the problem is how can I find the pdf of $X+Y$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Sum of random variables**

If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables with respective density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, then the sum $Z = X + Y$ is a random variable with density function $f_Z(z)$, where $f_z$ is the *convolution* of $f_X$ and $f_Y$.

**Convolutions**

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables with respective density functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$, then the *convolution* $f*g$ of $f$ and $g$ is the function given by:

$(f * g)(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(z - y)g(y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(z - y)f(x)dx$

**Sum of exponential random variables**

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ and density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. Let $Z = X + Y$, then

$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(z - y)g(y)dy$

$ = \int_{0}^{z} \lambda e^{-\lambda(z - y)}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}dy$

$ = \int_{0}^{z} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z}dy$

$ = \lambda^2 z e^{-\lambda z}$

A very good tutorial on sums of random variables can be found [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf).